# Pointing domain name to website server

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Ok so I'm still kinda new on this whole 'website server' topic. I just recently bought a domain from Google and I want to point that domain to my xampp server, or do I even point it to the Xampp server? I have put all my html, css, php, and mysql in the 'htdocs' folder in Xampp, and i want to run the website off my computer. How do I get the domain to point to my files?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a duplicate, but I'm in a hurry and you asked a 3-fold question.

Your domain name translates to a number through DNS. Look up how to use Dynamic DNS, I used afraid.org's (if they're still around, you can use, they were free, I don't know about now).

You have the hosting (2nd part) so that's good.

3rd part, setup port forwarding (should say "port fowarding" in router settings) in your router for 80 and 8080 (HTTP) to go to your local pc. You can find that by going to the command line (type "cmd" into the run box) and then ipconfig, by itself, then hit "Enter". Should be 192.168 something or 10.0.blah.blah. (Depends on router and type of network)

Comment: Make sure XAMPP is "on", to add to the "hosting". DNS isn't instant either, might take hours

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Domains

Go to configure domains

Add a custom resource record:

Name: @

Type: A

TTL: 1H

IPV4 Address: The IP adress of your Xampp server

This will forward your domain to the server, to also forward www.yourdomain do this:

Name: www

Type: CNAME

TTL: 1H

IPV4 Address: yourdomain